# Holdout MAPEs in SAS PROC ARIMA and SAS Forecast Studio don't match

Tags: time-series, arima

I have a Time Series (ARIMA) model in SAS, modelled using proc ARIMA which I am trying to replicate in SAS Forecasting Studio. What I see is that The parameter estimates in both are very similar (which is surprising, since my colleagues haven't had such luck, but I digress), but the MAPEs calculated with a Holdout of 7 months does not match.  I would understand the parameters not matching, with the numerical optimization algorithms giving different results with different initial values, but the MAPEs not matching is very puzzling.
Has anyone else here come across this, or has any idea what might be the case?
DO you need any more information to address this issue?

Thanks,
V

Comment: You could reach out to SAS tech support directly.